# Superponer div encima de google mapas jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Estoy realizando una aplicación en la cual quiero que al presionar un punto del mapa aparezca un menú superpuesto al mapa a la derecha en el cual mostrar datos, el problema es que no consigo que el menú aparezca encima del mapa, si no que lo que consigo es que se extienda la pagina un 30% más a la derecha, ¿Cómo podría lograrlo?

CSS

```
   #map {
         
        width:100%;  
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      
      #menuMap{
         visibility: hidden;
          position: absolute;
          width: 30%;
          height: 100%;
          padding-top: 70px;
          float: right;
         display: inline-block;
      }
      
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

HTML

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="menuMap"><p>hello world</p></div>
```

JQUERY

```
 function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          center: {
            lat: 40.6059969,
            lng: -3.706213,
          },
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
        });

    var image = {
          url: '../resources/logoMap.png', //ruta de la imagen
        
  };

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: 40.617335, lng: -3.703045},
          map: map,
          icon: image,
    title: 'Sequopro'
        });

 marker.addListener("click", () => {
    
    var divIsVisible;

    divIsVisible = $('#menuMap').is(':visible');
    
    if (divIsVisible){
        $('#menuMap').hide(3000);

    }else{
         $('#menuMap').show(3000);
        
    }  
        // window.location = "particulas1.php";
        });
```

Y este es el efecto que consigo al clickar en el punto del mapa, el mapa se extiende hacia la derecha y muestra el menú, pero lo que quiero es que se superponga encima del mapa, no que extienda la página, gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás posicionando como absolute wl contenedor, por lo que no necesitas flotar el elemento con:

```
float: right;
```

En su lugar usa:

```
#menuMap {
   right: 0;
}
```

Si el contenedor queda debajo del mapa, usa `z-index` con un número alto para posicionarlo por encima. Procura usar una cantidad que no te de conflicto por ejemplo, con el menú principal del sitio.